# Leer archivo TXT y usar datos para crear XML

Tags: php, xml

Quiero leer la información en el txt y traspasarla a un archivo XML.
He averiguado usando EXPLODE de PHP pero no he logrado resultados para leer bien el archivo de texto

Text File Data:

```
 33|50363|2020-02-03|0|2||1|2020-02-03} 
 89371100-7|REPETTO Y GAJARDO LIMITADA|MATERIALES DE CONSTRUCCION-PINTURAS-ARTICULOS ELECTRICOS-MENAJE-HERRAMIENTAS|523410|||Av. Egana 897|PENALOLEN|SANTIAGO|JESUS ALONSO|}
```

Tanto IdDoc como Emisor terminan con }

Como se debería ver en XML:

```
      <IdDoc>
        <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
        <Folio>50363</Folio>
        <FchEmis>2020-02-03</FchEmis>
        <TipoDespacho>2</TipoDespacho>
        <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
        <FchVenc>2020-02-03</FchVenc>
      </IdDoc>
      <Emisor>
        <RUTEmisor>89371100-7</RUTEmisor>
        <RznSoc>REPETTO Y GAJARDO LIMITADA</RznSoc>
        <GiroEmis>MATERIALES DE CONSTRUCCION-PINTURAS-ARTICULOS ELECTRICOS-MENAJE-HERRAMIENTAS</GiroEmis>
        <Acteco>523410</Acteco>
        <DirOrigen>Av. Egana 897</DirOrigen>
        <CmnaOrigen>PENALOLEN</CmnaOrigen>
        <CiudadOrigen>SANTIAGO</CiudadOrigen>
        <CdgVendedor>JESUS ALONSO</CdgVendedor>
      </Emisor>
```

Comment: Por favor, incluye en la pregunta como lo estás intentando leer.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  para mejorar la pregunta. Falta que muestres lo que has intentado, qué resultados o errores tienes. Y explicar también cuáles son los criterios de separación, los cuales para casos como estos deben ser siempre los mismos. Por decir algo: *Lo que indica el cierre de `IdDoc` es siempre esto `}`, o bien, el bloque `Emisor` se encuentra entre `}` y `}`; hay siempre en cada bloque `N` datos y deben asignarse a los items indicados según el ejemplo y esto siempre es así*. Por otra parte el ejemplo que muestras es inválido, ¿dónde se cierra el bloque `Encabezado`?

Comment: Otra cosa que no queda clara es ¿qué ocurre con los espacios en blanco, pues hay muchos entre `||`? ¿a qué corresponden, cómo deberían manejarse? En este tipo de conversiones se necesita un criterio claro, de lo contrario, te va a funcionar en unos casos, pero no en otros.

Comment: tiene toda la pinta de poder utilizar `fgetcsv` y tratar el archivo como si fuese un csv dividido por el simbolo `|`. echa un vistazo en la documentacion de php: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php